# Hair particle system hides and I don't have enough of control

Tags: particles, hair

[image: Problem 2]

I had a lot of problems while working with the particle system,

My story: I make a realistic squirrel in a blender. Everything was fine, I made her hair systems for different parts separately: head, ears and tail and body. Then I took up rigging. After that, I decided to return to the hair and then problem number 1 happened.

Problem number 1 The hair system fell off after rigging. I don't know if this is related to the rigging itself but what could have caused this? Before the rig, I combed them and they were in their place and after they were all straight (not combed) and not in their places. (I have already started work again, but suddenly someone knows because of what this could happen so that I would know what to do next time)

After that, I decided not to get upset and start making hair systems from the beginning (+ interpolated), but I ran into new problems that were not there before
problem number 2 - the entire length of my hair is the same in this segment, but for some reason some hair became smaller or disappeared altogether and bald patches appeared on the bottom - curves (with which we comb the hair) are not displayed in these places - these bald patches occurred just while I was combing my hair and this is not the first time.

(that is, problem number 2 - the disappearance or shortening of hair
and problem number 3 is the disappearance of curves controllers)

Comment: There’s just enough grammatical problems here to make the question not make sense. Might be translation errors. Regardless, please only describe the problems, one at a time, and not put it in story format.

Comment: Problem 1 might be caused by the modifiers order. The armature for the rig must be on top (or at least above) the particle system modifier. Otherwise, the hair does not move with the animation/pose.

Comment: Problem 2: sounds like the combed hair particles are inside of the mesh. There is an option named "[Deflect Emitter](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/particles/mode.html#tools)" and a value for the distance in the tool settings. Have you tried this? - Oh, wait you have it active in the screenshot. Then I don't know.